HXAM is installed but not working Android Studio
I installed Android Studio to start learning, but when I pressed Run it told me that I didn't have HXAM installed.
I tried to install it through the SDK Tools and it gave me this error:
Packages to install: - Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) - Deprecated (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)



Preparing "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) - Deprecated v.7.6.5".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_v7_6_5.zip
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) - Deprecated v.7.6.5" ready.
Installing Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) - Deprecated in C:\Users\Borisas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) - Deprecated v.7.6.5" complete.
Failed to update status to COMPLETE
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) - Deprecated v.7.6.5" failed.
Failed packages:
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) - Deprecated (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)

Alongside, it gave me this link to install HXAM manually:
https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows
I managed to install it and when I put "sc query intelhaxm" into the cmd it says this:
SERVICE_NAME: intelhaxm
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0


But Android Studio still isn't able to access it...
virtualization is enabled.
And I have tried to unpacked my files and installed it using bat, it still didn't work:
HAXM installed successfully, but not recognized by Android Studio 2.1
also I can't find the hyper-v in the control panell.
but when I was digging for other reasons I found that it's mentioned at the bottom of my system info:
enter image description here
I tried to disable it by following this guide but it only give me errors.
I have windows 10 and my winver is 22H2 if that helps.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowserver/forum/all/hyper-v-not-showing-up/86eadef9-8c32-493c-9a66-0c170b075d08
I've digged deeper than I myself can understand and don't even know what to google for anymore...

Recent versions of Aa droid emulator do no longer support deprecated HAXM technology. And HAXM was never working in systems with Hyper-V enabled. My suggestion: stop trying to ride a dead horse.

I am asking on how to install "intel x86 emulator accelerator (haxm installer)" in the SDK tools, because it is required to run your app. Unless you know a way of bypassing it.

HAXM is an VM accelerator even before Intel stopped development at the beginning of 2023 it wasn't required by the Android Emulator anymore. Seems like you are following an outdated tutorial. Please read it yourself: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#haxm-uninstall Use one of the two alternative accelerator technologies: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows
